# the expectation of a random variable of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

It's basically a textbook question however I want to make sure about every derivation step.

X, Z are random variables.

Z follows Bernoulli distribution. The probability density function of Z: $h(z) = x\delta(1) + (1-x)\delta(0)$,

where $\delta(\cdot)$ is Delta distribution, meaning,
$\delta(\cdot)=1, \text{ if } z=\cdot; \delta(1)=0, \text{ otherwise}$

The probability density function of X: $f_x$

Then we have $E[Z] = \int xf_xdx$.

**I was wondering if it is**,
$E[Z] = E[1\times x + 0\times (1-x)]=E[1\times \int xf_xdx]=\int xf_xdx$

If it is not, would you please show me the derivation steps? Thanks!

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Conditioned on $X=x$, $Z$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $x$, and thus $E[Z|X=x] = x$.  Thus, $$E[Z]=E[E[Z|X]]=E[X]=\int_0^1 xf_X(x)\mathrm dx.$$  You need to make sure that $X$ takes on values in $[0,1]$ with probability $1$, else all the above will make no sense because you cannot have a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $1.2$, say.

Comment: you can start to write h(z)=... explicitly as a function. Also, $E[X] = \int xf_xdx$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: that comment should be an answer

Comment: I don't quite understand the formula of the density h of Z. Maybe the OP or someone could explain?

Comment: @Tim I think it's like this $\delta(a)(z)=1$ if $z=a$ and $\delta(a)(z)=0$ if $z\neq a$ and then define $h(z)=x\delta(1)(z)+(1-x)\delta(0)(z)$ So $\delta(a)$ is a function that depends on $a$-you can call it alternatively and more clearly $\delta_a$

Comment: @BogdanLataianu: Thanks! So the probability measure of Z is actually a random one, as a mapping of X?

Comment: @Tim $E(Z|X)$ is a random variable and a mapping of X, not the p.m.f. of Z|X=x . Note that h(z) above is the p.m.f. of Z|X=x . Did you write h(z) explicitly? I don't want to spoil the hint for Shuai

Comment: @Shuai : You wrote $\delta(\cdot)=1$ if $z=\cdot$.  You must have meant $\delta(z)=1$ if $z=\cdot$.  And also: $\delta(z)=0$ otherwise rather than $\delta(1)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Tim Unless you meant the collection of p.d.f's Z|x is a random variable, which is an interesting question and I think it is true. But perhaps a sidetrack.

Comment: @BogdanLataianu: Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by leonbloy, I am converting my comment to an answer.

$X$ is a random variable that necessarily takes on values in $[0,1]$.

Conditioned on $X=x$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $Z$ is a Bernoulli random 
variable with parameter $x$.  Thus, conditioned on $X=x$,
the conditional expected value of $Z$ is
$$E[Z|X=x] = 1\times x + 0\times (1-x) = x.$$
The conditional expected value of $Z$ depends on the value taken
on by $X$,
that is, it is a *function* of the random variable $X$, and this random variable
is denoted as $E[Z|X]$.  In this instance, it is obvious that $E[Z|X]=X$ itself. Now,
the law of iterated expectations gives us that $E[Z]=E[E[Z|X]]$ where it
should be noted that the outer expectation is the expectation of a 
function of $X$. Thus, assuming that $X$ is a continuous random variable,
we have
$$E[Z]=E[E[Z|X]]=E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)\mathrm dx 
= \int_0^1 xf_X(x)\mathrm dx$$
since $f_X(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$ or $x > 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Marking this as the answer, however I would like to revise a bit. $$E[Z]=E[E(Z|X)]=\int E[Z|X=x]f(x)dx=\int xf(x)dx$$. Then the solution looks more right and does not depend on the obvious $E[Z|X]=X$.